# Is there an analytic function $f=u+iv$ defined on the unit disk, such that $u_x=0$ but $f$ is not constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

Using the following theorem,

$$\text{If }f\text{ is analytic on }D,\text{ and if }f'(z)=0\text{ for all }z\in D,\text{then }f\text{ is constant in }D $$

with Cauchy-Riemann equations has consequences:

$$\text{If }f=u+iv\text{ is analytic on }D\text{ with }u\text{ being constant, then }f\text{ is constant in }D $$

Which give me answer with "There is no such function" But when I see the solution I get the following statement:

> The answer is yes, there is such a function! Take for instance the function $f(z)=y-ix$ defined on the unit disk, where $z=x+iy$. The associated real part and imaginary part to $f$ are: $u(x,y)=y$ and $v(x,y)=-x$. So in particular, $u_x=0$.
> Furthermore, $u_x=0=v_y$ and $u_y=-1=-v_x$ (checking that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold), and those partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ are constant, thus clearly continuous in the unit disk. Therefore, $f$ is analytic in the unit disk. However, $f$ is not constant on the unit disk.

I couldn't connect my logic with the theorem. The solution seems to contradict the theorem, isn't it?

Comment: $u_x=0$ does not imply that $u$ would be a constant. Look at the given example again to understand why.

Comment: I didn't notice that $u_x=0$ and $u$ is constant are not same. To be constant $u$ need to be $u_x=0=u_y$, isn't it? @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Yes, if $u_x=0$, then $u$ depends only on $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Your theorem applies to functions $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ with $u(z)$ constant. The solution concerns a function $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ with $u(z)=y$, where $z=x+iy$ which is nonconstant. So the theorem does not apply.